# How to search only in chat history in Gmail

Tags: gmail, chat

When I do a search in Gmail, all my mail is searched, but I only want to search my chats. Is this possible?

Comment: It is amazing this is still broken from a UX point of view. How freaking hard is it to put a search button on the Google Chat window???

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `is:chats`. It will search for chat messages. Example: `is:chat monkey` — meaning any chat message including the word “monkey”.

[Here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) you can find a lot more advanced search options.

Comment: `is:chats` — with the plural for “chat”.

Answer (score 7):

`in:chat` also works, for searching conversations with the `label` chat

Answer (score 3):

*is:chat* & *in:chat*s are great, in the Gmail full Desktop Web view mode, ***BUT...***

- It doesn't work in Gmail's Basic HTML Desktop Web view;
- It doesn't work in Gmail's Mobile Web view;
- It doesn't work in the Google Voice web view;
- It doesn't work in the Gmail mobile app itself;
- As far as I can tell, it doesn't work within the API at all.

Since Gmail's full Desktop Web view no longer works in "Desktop" mode on many mobile devices, *it may be **impossible** to search your chat history from a mobile device*. (The Browser Agent reported by mobile browsers when operating in "Request Desktop" mode is deprecated & unsupported by most modern website designs; many issues exist which will not be resolved, ever.)

Any Messaging app that doesn't have Search is seriously lacking a major feature. It seems obvious to me that Hangouts (much less the original Chats app, which had a better name) should have a Search feature. Additionally, it is straight up idiotic that the Gmail app's Search feature doesn't support these flags.